# What is the best implementation for boolean in MySQL using Java to connect to the database?

Tags: java, mysql, boolean

I currently have a MySQL database set up with a Java client accessing and using the database. I need a Boolean data type in the database to determine whether some actions are allowed by various users of the database. What is the best implementation of Boolean that you can use in MySQL since there is no Boolean data type?

I know that `TinyInt` can be used with a `PreparedStatement` with `setByte(int parameterIndex, byte x` and I also know that `Bit` can also be used with `setBoolean(int parameterIndex, boolean x)`. Which of these is the better solution for a Boolean value? And if there is a better solution, what would it be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Boolean` in MySQL is a synonym for `TINYINT(1)`; `Bit` is, as well, if the number of bits is small enough. From the point of view of MySQL operation, it makes little difference which you use. What do you mean by "better"?

Comment: When I mean better I mean which is generally easier to implement or use when using Java as the client?

Comment: I'd use Y/N solution, as it is easier to read.

Comment: @nomadus - What's the Y/N solution?

Comment: Instead of 0 or 1, I'd rather use Y or N. I have seen several cases, where it is impossible to know if 0 is meant to be true or false. Difficult to read when the developer uses numbers to indicate boolean variables.

Comment: @nomadus - Yeah, I get that. Perhaps an `ENUM`  column would do the job. It stores as a `TINYINT(1)` and is readable like a string value.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be assuming that you can't address MySQL's `BOOL` using JDBC's `setBoolean` - you can.  As such, the best option is to declare the column as `BOOL` and use `setBoolean`.  Even though MySQL will alias your declaration to a `TINYINT`, your SQL declares what you want to use and your Java code makes it obvious at that level too.

Comment: @sheldonCooper, I've not checked, but from memory, yes.